# Hide and Show Label and Button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 labels and 2 text boxes and 1 buttons displayed.

When the page loads the `Name` and `Button` (will be initially displayed). Later when i click on the `Button` i need to display the `age` `label` and `textbox`. How can i do this ?

```
<ol>
     <li>
          <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Name">
             User name
          </asp:Label>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Name" Width="167px" />
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
     </li>                           
     <li>
          <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="age">age</asp:Label>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="age" TextMode="age" Width="240px" />
     </li>                         
</ol>
```

code for button press

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: some more clear explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set the label/textbox `Visible` property to `True` in server side. Alternatively, you could use `JavaScript` to avoid post backs to the server.

Add `OnClientClick` to your `button` :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="ShowLabel();"/>
```

and declare the `JavaScript` function on page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowLabel() {
      // Note that the client ID might be different from the server side ID
      document.getElementById('lblAge').style.display = 'inherit';
    }
</script>
```

You need to set the `Label` Display style to `none` initially.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblAge" style="display: none;" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="age">age</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try below code:

You need to set `Visible` property of controls to True or False according to your requirement. By default, all controls are visible on the screen whenever they are added on the page.You need to do following thing:

1. You need to remove `TextMode="age"` as there is not any supported textmode of type age.
2. Need to define id of control if you want to access a control server side in code behind. So define the ID of Label that you put corresponding to Age textbox.

By Default age label and textbox will not be visible by using below code:

```
      <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="age" Visible="false">age</asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="age" Width="240px"  Visible="false"/>
```

Code behind:
After button click age label and the textbox will be visible by using below code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblAge.Visible = true;
        age.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: It says that Label2 does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2):

First add `id` to elements and set `visible` false

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="age" Visible="false" Id="lbl1">age</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="age" TextMode="age" Width="240px" Visible="false" />
```

button click event set `visible` true

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl1.Visible = True;
    age.Visible = True;
}
```

Comment: it says the field `lbl1` does not exist in the current context

Comment: You should add `Id` attribute to your label.

Comment: you mean to change `ID` to `Id` ? in my code i am having it as `ID` is this correct?

Comment: No, I did not. Can you use age textbox with its Id? There may be Syntax error my code. Updated...

Comment: i tried replacing all `ID` with `Id`, and even tried it on textbox but it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

this is the basic concept of asp.net. you can use visible property of the control.

1. your TextMode enumeration is wrong. there is no Age enumeration for Textbox.TextMode [TextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textboxmode.aspx)

`<li>
              <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="age" id="lblAge">age</asp:Label>
              <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="age" TextMode="age" Width="240px" />
         </li>`

in code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lblAge.Visible=true;
  age.Visible=true;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how to refer `lblAge` from the aspx file to the C# code. As you have done in your code. (i'm a newbie)

Comment: Why have you used `ID` (upper case) for the textfield and lowercase id for the label. does it make any difference ?

Comment: i have still failed to get this work. any clue why? Am i missing a reference ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameLabel.Visible = false;
        NameBox.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameLabel.Visible = true;
        NameBox.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for a server side solution (to hide both the label and a control when control visible is changed):

> Client Side:

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="age" OnPreRender="OnPreRender_SetVisible">age</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="age" Width="240px" />
```

> Server Side:

```
    protected void OnPreRender_SetVisible(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = sender as Label;
        if(lbl != null) {
            var ctl = FindControlRecursive(Controls, lbl.AssociatedControlID);
            if(ctl != null)
            {
                lbl.Visible = ctl.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

> In a Utility Class:

```
    public Control FindControlRecursive(ControlCollection controls, string id)
    {
        foreach (Control ctl in controls)
        {
            var result = FindControlRecursive(ctl, id);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
    {
        if (root.ID == id)
        {
            return root;
        }
        foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
        {
            Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
            if (t != null)
            {
                return t;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Credit for recursive function: Oddur Magnusson/Jeff Atwood - https://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/