# Label false property cannot be changed programatically by button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

Having looked around at pages such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455371/hide-and-show-label-and-button), I cannot see why a label text will not display in a simple test page when a submit button is clicked.  As the file is short, I have included all coding, in case there is anything I have not thought of in the background.

The text does not display when the button is pressed in a render generated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in Visual Studio Express 2015. Where have I gone wrong?
Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="labelTest2.aspx.cs"
 Inherits="contact_labelTest2" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
    <title>Label Test</title>
 </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send"/>
      <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Visible="false">
       Test M AFTERessage</asp:Label>         
    </div>
    </form>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class contact_labelTest2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }
      protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
             lblMessage.Visible = true;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add [`OnClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event to the `Button`. Like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```